# Understanding Vectorization

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I'm trying to make some code more efficient, and am wondering how to vectorize this:

```
%==========================================================================
% MinutesInDayTable.m
% 
% Creates a table identifying every minute as an integer from 0 to 2400.

minuteTableInDay=zeros(24*60,1);
k=1;
for i=1:24
    for j=1:60
        minuteTableInDay(k) = ((i-1)*100+(j-1))*100;
        k=k+1;
    end
end
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of code ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Note that your code and description don't fully match.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another one:

```
minuteTableInDay = (datestr(0:1/24/60:1, 'HHMMSS')-48) * 10.^(5:-1:0)'
```

Have fun :)

Comment: For those trying to read it, the 48 is not related to hours or days, but is the character code for `'0'`, so the 'normal' (boring) way to do it would be `minuteTableInDay = num2str(datestr(0:1/24/60:1, 'HHMMSS'))`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: of course, `num2str `should be `str2num`. Note that that "boring solution" is quite a bit slower (`str2num` is not a builtin).

Answer (score 4):

That's easy, the general way to vectorize this computation is:

```
[I, J] = meshgrid(1:24, 1:60);                      %// 2-D arrays for I and J
minuteTableInDay = ((I - 1) * 100 + (J - 1)) * 100; %// Compute all values at once
minuteTableInDay = minuteTableInDay(:);             %// Convert to a column vector
```

The key to vectorizing this is supplying MATLAB with all the values, so that the operations can be performed for all elements at once.

In your case, your code contains basic arithmetic functions so you can further reduce your code (similar to Oleg's suggestion):

```
minuteTableInDay = bsxfun(@plus, (0:59)', (0:23) * 100) * 100;
```

Comment: Guess it is actually the same solution, but here is how I would do it:   `[H, M] = meshgrid(0:100:2300,0:59);minuteTableInDay=H(:)+M(:);`

Answer (score 3):

You can create time that goes from `0,...,115900,120000,...,235900`:

```
out = bsxfun(@plus, (0:59)' , 0:23)*100;
out = out(:);
```

If you want it to be `100,...,115900,120000,...,240000`, add this line:

```
out = [out(2:end); 240000]
```

Comment: +1. You're missing a factor of 100 when compared to the original code though.

Comment: @EitanT Thanks, I did not get that he wanted seconds as well at first.